# Issue in passing content as a body in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am calling an Azure Function(HTTP trigger) in Azure Data Factory and the body is coming from a lookup activity (@activity('Lookup1').output.value) which is something like this

```
"body":[
        {
            "BaseObject": "2|03|01|01",
            "BaseObjectDescription": "Cent",
            "CreateDate": "30.09.2021"
        },
        {
            "BaseObject": "9|03|01|01",
            "BaseObjectDescription": "Pent",
            "CreateDate": "30.09.2021"
        }]
```

The above json when passed as body to Azure function activity, I get error as "Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: S." But if I hardcode and pass the same value in body of Azure function I get the output. When I hardcode it, I see in debug mode the body is passed as something like this

```
"body": "[\n        {\n            \"BaseObject\": \"02|03|01|01\",\n            \"BaseObjectDescription\": \"Cent\",\n            \"CreateDate\": \"30.09.2021\" },\n        {\n            \"BaseObject\": \"04|03|01|01\",\n            \"BaseObjectDescription\": \"Pent",\n            \"CreateDate\": \"21.09.2021\",\n },\n]"
```

So question is how do I change the json I am getting from lookup activity to something like above so that my Function recognizes this as body in Azure Data Factory.

Here is my configuration of Azure Function Linked Service. Why open in Azure Portal is Disabled. The error I get in ADF for Azure Function Activity is

```
"
Call to provided Azure function 'Function1' failed with status-'InternalServerError' and message - 'Invoking Azure function failed with HttpStatusCode - InternalServerError.'." While in Azure Function Logs I see the error message as below:

2022-01-06T10:14:42.403 [Information] C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.
2022-01-06T10:14:42.826 [Error] Executed 'Function1' (Failed, Id=c7f2488f-e08f-49a3-8f10-4e82a10d9ac0, Duration=270ms)The argument 'length' is smaller than minimum of '1' (Parameter 'length')
2022-01-06T10:16:40.934 [Information] Executing 'Function1' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=5ff54bce-679d-4892-87a0-fb342ff02cc7)
2022-01-06T10:16:40.934 [Information] C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.
2022-01-06T10:16:40.994 [Error] Executed 'Function1' (Failed, Id=5ff54bce-679d-4892-87a0-fb342ff02cc7, Duration=2ms)Specified method is not supported.Specified method is not supported.
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi, Can you try converting the output to string `@string(activity('Lookup1').output.value)`and check?

Comment: I get a different error now. I have modified the question. Can you please check my configuration on Linked services. if something is wrong there

Comment: @string() dont work, it converts the body as [{\"BaseObject\":\"@.....}... If you see it removes the "]" from the json object and also lot other changes which is different from what I get by directly hardcoding the value

Comment: Your linked service configuration looks correct to me as per this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-azure-function-activity). Can you please provide the complete output of your lookup activity?

Comment: that has sensitive information .. can we connect over teams or any other way?

Comment: Sorry, can you check if the value you are getting from `@activity('Lookup1').output.value` is the same as what you have hardcoded? you can use set variables for testing.

Comment: the one I have hardcoded is same as  i get from @activity('Lookup1').output.value but when I use @string(activity('Lookup1').output.value) then that becomes different from what is hardcoded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the **lookup activity** value as `@activity('Lookup1').output.value[0]` inside the body of Azure Function activity.

**Lookup activity output:**

[image]

**Azure Function activity settings:**

**Body**: `@activity('Lookup1').output.value[0]`

[image]

The value shown in input to Azure functions:

[image]

Comment: my body is an array of json which is supposed to be passed [0] gives me first value of array. However I tried , and I get same error as passing the whole array from lookup activity. " [Error] Executed 'Function1' (Failed, Id=a48a3829-e923-4c12-bc8d-edaa2ff04c43, Duration=284ms)The argument 'length' is smaller than minimum of '1' (Parameter 'length')". I dont have any parameter length here